# Retrieving data from additional OptionTree pages

Tags: wordpress

Adding OptionTree pages is simple with the code below, but does anyone know how to retrieve the stored data?

```
/**
```

* Hook to register admin pages 
 */
add_action( 'init', 'register_options_pages' );

/**
 * Registers all the required admin pages.
 */
function register_options_pages() {

// Only execute in admin & if OT is installed
  if ( is_admin() && function_exists( 'ot_register_settings' ) ) {

```
// Register the pages
ot_register_settings( 
  array(
    array( 
      'id'              => 'custom_options',
      'pages'           => array(
        array(
          'id'              => 'test_page',
          'parent_slug'     => 'options-general.php',
          'page_title'      => 'Test Page',
          'menu_title'      => 'Test Page',
          'capability'      => 'edit_theme_options',
          'menu_slug'       => 'test-page',
          'icon_url'        => null,
          'position'        => null,
          'updated_message' => 'Test Page updated.',
          'reset_message'   => 'Test Page reset.',
          'button_text'     => 'Save Changes',
          'show_buttons'    => true,
          'screen_icon'     => 'options-general',
          'contextual_help' => null,
          'sections'        => array(
            array(
              'id'          => 'test_section',
              'title'       => __( 'Test Section', 'motif-core' )
            )
          ),
          'settings'        => array(
            array(
              'id'          => 'test_section_input',
              'label'       => 'Test Input',
              'desc'        => 'Pretty freaking awesome!',
              'std'         => '',
              'type'        => 'text',
              'section'     => 'test_section',
              'class'       => ''
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I tried this $my_plugin_options = get_option('custom_options'); but it only shows the word 'array' on the front end?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to retrieve the stored data:

$my_plugin_options = get_option('custom_options');

echo $my_plugin_options['test_section_input'];